# How to create and send a 3-Dimensional Array using $_GET when submitting a form?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, get

I have an HTML `form` for adding credentials of different candidates. This data will later be stored in a database. Now for each candidate, there is an `input[type=text]` field for `Name`, `SSN` each, and one or more `input[type=text]` fields for `Mobile`. Once candidate can have more than one mobile numbers.

Now when this form is submitted, I wanted the data to be posted such that:

- There is an outer array of all candidates. Let's call it `$allCandidatesArray`.
- The outer array `$allCandidatesArray` contains an array for each candidate.
- Inside each of these inner arrays, the first two elements viz. `$nameInput` and `$ssnInput` are simple String values, which the third element is again an array, whose elements are mobile numbers of the candidate. Remember that a candidate can have more than one mobile numbers. Hence an Array!

So something like this should be sent in **`$_GET["allCandidatesArray"]`:

```
$allCandidatesArray = {
    {
        "name"=> "Amy",
        "ssn" => 123,
        "mobile" => {
             22,
             33
         }
    },

    {
        "name"=> "Bob",
        "ssn" => 333,
        "mobile" => {
             11
         }
    }
}
```

**So I tried something which you can see below in my SSCCE example, but what is sent in `$_GET["allCandidatesArray]` is strange when printed to the screen:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [ssnValueInput] => ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) ) [2] => Array ( [ssnValueInput] => ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ) ) )
```

The question is that how do I fix this?

[image]

***index.php:***

```
<?php 

print_r($_GET["allCandidatesArray"]);

?>


<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/materialize.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/material-icons.css" />
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />-->

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>

    <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>

<form id="credentialsForm" action="" method="get">

    <fieldset id="wrapper" class="container">
        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][nameInput]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][ssnValueInput]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput">SSN</label>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3">
                <input type="text" id="mobileInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][][]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput">Mobile</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col l1 offset-l1" id="addMobileButtonWrapper">
                <a id="addMobileButton" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

        </fieldset><!--#wrapper-->
















        <fieldset id="wrapper" class="container">
        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][nameInput]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][ssnValueInput]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput">SSN</label>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3">
                <input type="text" id="mobileInput" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[][][]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput">Mobile</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col l1 offset-l1" id="addMobileButtonWrapper">
                <a id="addMobileButton" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

        </fieldset><!--#wrapper-->























        <div class="row" id="submitFormRow">
            <div class="col l4 offset-l4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-light waves-effect">Add Candidates</button>
            </div>
        </div><!--.row #s -->

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

***scripts.js:***

```
$(document).on("click", "#addMobileButton", function() {

    //alert("#addMobileButton clicked.");//check  

    var parentRow = $(this).closest(".row");

    parentRow.after('<div id="rowAddedForCandidatesMobile" class="row valign-wrapper"><div class="input-field col l3"><input type="text" id="mobileInput" class="validate"/><label for="mobileInput">Mobile</label></div><div class="col l1" id="addMobileButtonWrapper"><a id="addMobileButton" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div></div>');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this.

First of all ids are unique so all of the duplicate ids are not going to fly. 
E.G `<fieldset id="wrapper"`

Second when PHP sees and empty array index ([]) in a name, it assigns it a new index number. If you keep this in mind then it's easy to create the array structure you want by limiting the number of empty array indexes, and instead explicitly assigning the index.

Also I went through and changed some of your duplicate ids to class names, because class names are not unique and you should be able to use them to grab the elements you want to validate later on.

In the code below, each fieldset has a unique id that we can use to tie dynamically created mobile inputs to an array. E.G mobile inputs in the  fieldset `id="CandidateWrapper2"` should be named `allCandidatesArray[2][mobile][]` because we don't care about the order of the mobile numbers, but we do care which candidate the input is associated with.

The JavaScript has comments and descriptive variable names, but let me know if you don't understand what it's doing.

```
<?php

    print_r($_GET["allCandidatesArray"]);

?>


<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/materialize.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/material-icons.css" />
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />-->

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>

    <link href="images/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>

<form id="credentialsForm" action="" method="get">

    <fieldset id="CandidateWrapper1" class="container candidate-wrapper" >
        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="nameInput1" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[1][name]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput1" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[1][ssn]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput">SSN</label>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <div class="row valign-wrapper mobile-holder">

            <div class="input-field col l3">
                <input type="text" class="validate mobile-input" name="allCandidatesArray[1][mobile][]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput">Mobile</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col l1 offset-l1 add-mobile-button-wrapper" >
                <a class="add-mobile-button btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

    </fieldset><!--#wrapper-->






    <fieldset id="CandidateWrapper2" class="container candidate-wrapper" >
        <div class="row valign-wrapper">

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="nameInput2" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[2][name]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
                <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput2" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[2][ssn]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput">SSN</label>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <div class="row valign-wrapper mobile-holder">

            <div class="input-field col l3">
                <input type="text" id="mobileInput2" class="validate  mobile-input" name="allCandidatesArray[2][mobile][]"/>
                <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput">Mobile</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col l1 offset-l1 add-mobile-button-wrapper" >
                <a class="add-mobile-button btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
            </div>

        </div><!--.row-->



        <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

    </fieldset><!--#wrapper-->


    <div class="row" id="submitFormRow">
        <div class="col l4 offset-l4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn waves-light waves-effect">Add Candidates</button>
        </div>
    </div><!--.row #s -->

</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", ".add-mobile-button", function() {
        var  $this = $(this);
        var $container = $this.closest('.candidate-wrapper');
        var _regex =/CandidateWrapper(\d+)/;
        var _found = $container.attr('id').match(_regex);
        var _candidateNumber = _found[1];

        // get and update our HTML template
        var $newRow = $($('#TemplateHTML').html());
        var _newName = 'allCandidatesArray['.concat(_candidateNumber,'][mobile][]');
        $newRow.find('.mobile-input').attr("name",_newName);

        // add new row to the DOM
        $this.closest('.add-mobile-button-wrapper').before($newRow);
    });
</script>

<!-- The browser will ignore scripts with types it doesn't understand. So it doesn't run this -->
<script type="text/html" id="TemplateHTML">
    <div class="input-field col l3">
        <input type="text" class="validate mobile-input" name="allCandidatesArray[WE_ARE_REPLACING_THIS][mobile][]"/>
        <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput">Mobile</label>
    </div>
</script>

</body>

</html>
```